# Thermal noise phasor amplitudes are Rayleigh distributed. How are voltages at the antenna distributed?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation, mathematics, antennas

**Background.**
Consider an ideal antenna. For ideal polarized thermal noise treated as a random phasor sum, bivariate Gaussian statistics apply to the resultant phasor (call it $\vec{v}$) that is observed at any given moment in the antenna. That is, the phasor sum's *real* and *imaginary* parts are indepent Gaussian normal variables. The amplitude of said phasor sum thus follows (in some books *by definition*) the Rayleigh distribution:

$$P_A = {a\over \sigma^2}e^{-a^2/2\sigma^2}$$

...where $a = \sqrt{\mathrm{Re}({\vec{v}}) + \mathrm{Im}({\vec{v}})}$, and the scale parameter $\sigma^2 = \overline{\mathrm{Re(
\vec{v}})^2} + \overline{\mathrm{Im(
\vec{v}})^2}$, which works out to be the square of the $\mathrm{RMS}$ voltage at the antenna.

---

I'd like to model the actual *voltage* distribution observed at an ideal antenna due to thermal noise. While there are a multitude of sources describing the physics of the Rayleigh-distributed thermal noise *amplitude*, most approximate the voltage distribution as  a simple Gaussian, which is imperfect (a folded Gaussian differs significantly from a Rayleigh distribution).

**Question.** How are the voltages observed at the antenna distributed? The amplitudes are Rayleigh-distributed... what does that mean for the actual voltage values? I've found [one source](https://www.phys.hawaii.edu/%7Eidlab/taskAndSchedule/ARA/Rician.pdf) that states the following:

> In the absence of a signal, the electric field due to [...] thermal
> noise can be represented as a sum of [complex numbers] whose
> projections on the real and imaginary axes are independent Gaussian
> random variables. Summing these phasors and taking the real part to
> get a realized voltage results in a Gaussian two-sided voltage
> distribution, or equivalently a Rayleigh [amplitude] distribution.

It isn't clear to me what is meant by a "two-sided Gaussian", nor is it clear to me what parameters that Gaussian would take (e.g. how to find $\sigma$?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbf z = \mathbf x + \mathfrak j \mathbf y$ where the random variates $\mathbf {x,y}$ are independent and *normal* distributed with zero mean, that is: $\mathbf {x,y} := \mathcal N (0, \sigma)$. If your signal, say voltage, at the antenna is $s(t)e^{\mathfrak j \omega t}$ and noise bandwidth $W$ at noise temperature $T$ then set $\sigma^2 = k_B T W$ and your sampled signal in the additive noise will be $r_n = s(n/2W) + \mathbf z_n$

---

If you only have noise and measure the noise samples with an I/Q detector then on both arms the pdf of the instantaneous voltage will be $n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} exp\big(\frac {-x^2}{2\sigma^2}\big)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I follow, however I'm wondering what functional form the PDF of the noise voltage (or signal, if you like)-- assuming *only* noise is observed --takes. That is, what is the PDF of what you call $r_n$, assuming only thermal noise is observed?