# Why is thermal noise Gaussian distributed in voltage, but Rayleigh distributed in amplitude?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, voltage, antennas

This is a follow-up to a similar but distinct question [I recently asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/715732/).

---

**Background.**

Consider an ideal [antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_(radio)). For ideal polarized thermal noise treated as a sum of random, complex [phasors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor), [bivariate Gaussian statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case) apply to the resultant phasor observed at any given moment in the antenna. That is to say that the observed phasor, call it:

$$\mathbb{z} = x+iy$$

has $\mathrm{Im}$ and $\mathrm{Re}$ parts, which are independent Gaussian normal variables, centered on $0$. The amplitude of said phasor follows (in some books *by definition*) a [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution).

If you have some signal *in addition* to thermal noise, you can imagine the bivariate Gaussian appended to the tip of the "signal phasor". The amplitude of the phasor sum observed at the antenna is then distributed according to a Rician (a noncentral generalization of the Rayleigh distribution).

The actual "signal" (voltages, say) observed at the antenna are Gaussian distributed. However, with mean $\mu = 0$, and [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) given by something like:

$$\sigma = k_BTW$$

(where $T$ is the noise temperature (in Kelvin, $\mathrm{K}$) and $W$ is the bandwidth (frequency, $\mathrm{Hz}$).

---

**Question.**

I can make the math work, however I'm having trouble *intuitively* reconciling a Rayleigh amplitude distribution with a Gaussian signal/voltage distribution ("signal" here refers to what is measured at the antenna... in this case, *pure* thermal noise).

Consider an example Rayleigh amplitude distribution, and corresponding Gaussian signal/voltage distribution, for some thermal noise:

[image]

According to the Rayleigh amplitude distribution, we should expect to see *no* thermal noise with amplitude $0$, and little thermal noise with amplitude *near* $0$. The signal/voltage distribution, however, *peaks* at $0$. Moreover, I would expect the amplitude distribution to be the absolute value of the signal/voltage distribution, the result of which would be a folded Gaussian, *not* a Rayleigh distribution.

I can see how the Rayleigh distribution is obtained from the bivariate Gaussian distributed thermal noise phasors (please correct me if I'm wrong in my intuition).

Recall that a probability is obtained from a PDF ([probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)), by integrating over some region. So, the probability at the center of the bivariate Gaussian is zero.

As we move farther out, one might imagine integrating over a ring corresponding to all phasors of some magnitude. Although the bivariate Gaussian peaks near its center, the ring over which we integrate is smaller. As we move out to phasors of larger magnitude, the ring over which we integrate increases in area, and so does the value of the Rayleigh distribution. At some point, although the ring over which we are integrating continues to grow, the value of the bivariate Gaussian drops so steeply that we reach a peak in the Rayleigh distribution, and it begins to decline.

I can't, however, intuitively reconcile the Gaussian signal/voltage distribution with the Rayleigh amplitude distribution. How does this work out?

Comment: A few equations (what is added to what) could help clarify your question... and maybe even guide you to the answer.

Comment: Not sure how far my answer goes in answering your question - I am still not sure that I fully understand it. Still, it would be against the forum policies to put it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help a bit. Consider two normally distributed variables $X_1,X_2\sim N(\mu=0,\sigma=1) $. Then $X_1,X_1^2,X_1^2+X_2^2$ and $\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$ will produce the following plots. Notice that only once the square root is introduced the PDF goes to zero at zero. To be honest I don't know why it does that at the moment.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Edit: It is not solely due to the square root, as shown by this plot below. This means that the story you describe with integration over rings is true for 3 normally distributed variables or more. Note that without the square root a chi-square distribution is produced, not a Rayleigh distribution.

[image]

Comment: and a $\chi^2$ distribution with 2 degrees of freedom is and exponential distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This helps a bit. I guess my question is really about the Rayleigh PDF tending to zero near 0. I guess I just need to think on it a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

The amplitude is $\rho^2=x^2+y^2$, which is by definition positive, and which will obey Reyleigh distribution, if $x,y$ are a bivariate normal. Note also that detector is always a quadratic detector - it averages the squared signal (voltage or current) over some time window (since averaging the value itself always gives zero).

Comment: $\rho$ is Rayleigh distributed. $\rho^2$ is exponential.

Comment: @JEB yes, obviously.